# SQL Server query for related products

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to get related products but the issue which I'm facing is that there is product photos table which has one-to-many relationship with products table, so when I get products by matching category Id it also returns multiple product photos with that product which i do not want. I want only one product photo from product photos table of specific product. Is there any way to use distinct in joins or any other way? what I have done so far....

```
 SELECT [Product].[ID],
  ,[Thumbnail]
  ,[ProductName]
  ,[Model]
  ,[SKU]
  ,[Price]
  ,[IsExclusive]
  ,[DiscountPercentage]
  ,[DiscountFixed]
  ,[NetPrice]
  ,[Url]
  FROM [dbo].[Product]
  INNER JOIN [ProductPhotos] ON [ProductPhotos].[ProductID]=[Product].[ID]
  INNER JOIN [ProductCategories] ON [ProductCategories].[ProductID]= 
  [Product].[ID]
  WHERE [ProductCategories].[CategoryID]=4
```

And the result I am getting is...

[image: IMG1]

Product Photos table has

[image: IMG2]

Is there any way to use distinct or group by on product Id column in product photos table to return only one row from photos table.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 maybe?

Comment: I dont want only one record from whole query result. If i have 3 photos in product photos table of one product then its returning three products by matching productId in product photos table which i dont want. Hope you get the question now?

Comment: `product photos table which has one-to-many relationship with products table` So which row of the product photo table you want ?

Comment: @NerdProgrammer from  Product Photos table you want distinct productID righgt? but can you please tell us what is the logic of getting single product id from this table

Comment: there is 4rows of productID 2 which one you will pick and on what basis

Comment: Its returning 4 rows meaning 4 photos of same product. So when i display on page it shows 4 photos of same product in related product partial page.

Comment: For product 2, there are four Thumbnails t-5sets-chair-1/2/3/4.
which one photo you want as your result?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `inner join`, use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM dbo.Product p CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) pp.*
      FROM ProductPhotos pp
      WHERE pp.ProductID = p.id
      ORDER BY NEW_ID()
     ) pp INNER JOIN
     ProductCategories pc
     ON pc.ProductID = p.id
WHERE pc.CategoryID = 4;
```

Notes:

- The `ORDER BY NEWID()` chooses a *random* photo.  You can order by specific columns to get the earliest, latest, biggest, or whatever.
- Note that I added table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should qualify all column names in your query, so it is clear which tables they come from.
- I removed the superfluous square braces.  They just make the query harder to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to return one row for `ProductID`, like this:

```
JOIN (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY PhotoID) rn
      FROM [ProductPhotos]) [ProductPhotos]
ON [ProductPhotos].[ProductID]=[Product].[ID] AND [ProductPhotos].rn = 1
```

Instead of this:

```
JOIN [ProductPhotos] ON [ProductPhotos].[ProductID]=[Product].[ID]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use sub query in join with distinct instead of joining table directly.

you can create alias and use that column as distinct in select statement, but it will create performance issues when having loads of data inside.

if you have 3 different photos for same product Id (like 2). you can use sub-query with top 1 order by PK desc to get latest picture.